# how can I handle invalid data rows using custom exceptions in Java?

Tags: java, exception

I want to handle invalid data rows when importing and parsing a csv file in Java. In case my program does not accommodate a specific value (e.g. professor as a Profession) a InvalidCharacteristicException should be thrown. My program should handle such exceptions by issuing a warning statement and show the line number in the config file where the error was found.I tried to throw each enum using try-catch.

Here is my enum data.

```
public enum Profession {
DOCTOR, CEO, CRIMINAL, HOMELESS, UNEMPLOYED , UNKNOWN, NONE;
}

public enum BodyType {
SLIM, OBESE, ATHLETIC, UNSPECIFIED; 
}
```

Here is what the csv looks like.

```
  [0],    [1], [2],    [3]  ,    [4]    ,   [5]   ,  [6] ,   [7]  ,  [8] , [9]
class, gender, age, bodyType, profession, pregnant, isYou ,species, isPet, role
scenario:green,   ,         ,           ,         ,        ,      ,      ,
person, female, 24, average ,           , FALSE   ,        ,      ,      , passenger
animal, male  ,  4,         ,           , FALSE   ,        , dog  , TRUE , pedestrian
.
.
```

Here is what I am thinking and what I've tried. Here is my custom exception.

```
public class InvalidCharacteristicException extends Exception
{   
    public InvalidCharacteristicException(int configLineNum) 
    {       
        super("WARNING: invalid characteristic in config file in line" + 
             + configLineNum);
    }
}
```

Below is part of my readCsv() method and what I've tried.

```
File file = new File(csvFile); 
FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);   
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
String line = "";
String[] tempArr;

try{
    if (BodyType.valueOf().toLowerCase() != tempArr[3]){
        throw new InvalidCharacteristicException();
    }

}catch(InvalidCharacteristicException e){
    InvalidCharacteristicException();
}
try{

    if (Profession.valueOf().toLowerCase() != tempArr[4]){
        throw new InvalidCharacteristicException();
    }
}catch(InvalidCharacteristicException e){
    InvalidCharacteristicException()
}
```

Here is how I want this code to change so that the code iterates through the whole rows of the csv file and finds the line number where an exception error occurs..

```
for (total rows of the csv file)
{
    if (tempArr[3] != BodyType.valueOf().toLowerCase())
    {

        throw new InvalidCharacteristicException();
    }
    if (tempArr[4] != Profession.valueOf().toLowerCase())
    {
        throw new InvalidCharacteristicException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok So I take two cases of your scenario,first assuming you are planning to throw error and stop execution when you encounter wrong input and in other you planning to continue the execution but just logging a warning about wrong input. Both codes snippet are given below:

```
File file = new File(csvFile); 
FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);   
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
String line = "";
String[] tempArr;
String separator = ",";
int length=0;

    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       tempArr = line.split(separator);
       length = tempArr.length;
       for(int column=0;column < length ; column++) {


            if (column==3 && BodyType.valueOf().toLowerCase() != tempArr[column]){
                    throw new InvalidCharacteristicException(column);
            }else if (column==4 && BodyType.valueOf().toLowerCase() != tempArr[column]){
                throw new InvalidCharacteristicException(column);
            }
        }
    }
```

Above one is to throw and stop execution

```
File file = new File(csvFile); 
FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);   
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
String line = "";
String[] tempArr;
String separator = ",";
int length=0;

    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       tempArr = line.split(separator);
       length = tempArr.length;
       for(int column=0;column < length ; column++) {

         try{
            if (column==3 && BodyType.valueOf().toLowerCase() != tempArr[column]){
                    throw new InvalidCharacteristicException(column);
            }else if (column==4 && BodyType.valueOf().toLowerCase() != tempArr[column]){
                throw new InvalidCharacteristicException(column);
            }
          }catch(InvalidCharacteristicException e){
            //Log error or warn using object e
          }catch(Exception e){
            //Log error or warn using object e
          }
        }
    }
```

This one just continues execution.
Don't forget to close the opened resources. I have not included them in code as main focus was looping on records.